# Import Edited data back to Gravity Forms Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, database, wordpress, csv, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using a gravity forms plugin and it takes long to edit the entries or data from the plugin interface itself. I can export data as a csv file and edit it in excel or any other csv supporting application. Now the thing is how can I import the data back into gravity forms without creating duplicates and only updated the fields I have edited? Or is there a plugin that can be used to import the data back and only update the fields I have edited?

Your assistance would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this before but I wanted to at least share it's existence with you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-mass-import/

A few people I know who have used it say that it does a great job with simple form data but for more complex field types, it doesn't hold up as well.

Comment: Strangely, that plugin doesn't work with the CSV export that Gravity Forms creates. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-of-available-fields-is-missing-several-fields#post-5867279